# Highlight columns with differences between two excel sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Thus far, I have written a VBA script to compare two sheets and highlight the particular cells with the differences. I am trying to highlight the headers or columns of the cells where these differences lie. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub checked()
    Dim mycol As Range
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim shtSheet2 As Worksheet
    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    For Each mycell In shtSheet2.UsedRange
      If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then
        mycell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        'mycell.EntireColumn.Interior.Color = vbYellow
      End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify what problem(s) you are having?

Comment: I am unable to highlight column (it only highlights cell). Not sure how to go about highlighting column

Comment: `mycell.entireColumn.Interior.Color = vbRed`

Comment: Instead of entire column can this just highlight column header? Highlighting all is causing the program to crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub checked()
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim shtSheet1 As Worksheet
    Set shtSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each mycell In .UsedRange
            If Not mycell.Value = shtSheet1.Range(mycell.Address).Value Then .Cells(1, mycell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Next
    End with
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the header is in row 1, you can call out the column value of mycell and specify row 1:
`cells(1,mycell.Column).Interior.Color = vbRed`